# Bulk conversion of leads results in non-bulk behavior

Tags: apex, governorlimits, lead-conversion, bulkification

I'm fairly certain that I've discovered a bug.

When trying to convert leads using the `Database.convertLead(List<LeadConvert>,Boolean allorNothing)` in my org, the resulting conversions exhibit non-bulk behavior. I've found a link to [this bug](https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p300000008Z53AAE), which indicates that this only happened in certain conditions, and that it was fixed, but I'm still experiencing something similar, but in all cases--not just when specifying the same AccountId. I've tried deleting all managed packages, deactivating process builder logic (which I know has previously experienced issues with bulk processing), and changing the API version of my Apex classes that do the conversion to lower versions where I've made the same functionality work in previous organizations. However, nothing seems to resolve the issue.

Steps to reproduce: Run the following anonymous block of Apex from the developer console:

```
    List<Lead> test = new List<Lead>();
    for(Integer i=0;i<5;i++){
        Lead l = new Lead(
            LastName = 'Test',
            Company = 'Test',
            Email = 'test@test'+i+'.com'
        );
        test.add(l);
    }
    insert test;
    List<Database.LeadConvert> lcL= new List<Database.LeadConvert>();
    for(Lead l : test){
        Database.LeadConvert lc = new Database.LeadConvert();
        lc.setLeadId(l.Id);
        lc.setDoNotCreateOpportunity(true);
        lc.setConvertedStatus('Qualified');
        lcL.add(lc);
    }
    Database.LeadConvertResult[]lcrList = Database.convertLead(lcL);
```

I then have a very basic trigger on leads:

```
trigger LeadTrigger on Lead (after update) {
            System.debug('Running Lead Trigger');
        }
```

I would expect this debug statement to fire once, when the leads are marked as read-only following the conversion. However, I see five debug statements in the log.

In terms of business impact, this slows down the process of converting leads (as account and contact triggers/workflows/process builder fire one-by-one rather than in bulk) and sometimes causes CPU timeout issues.

Has anyone else experienced anything like this? The client has Standard support, which doesn't cover development so Salesforce support has not been helpful. The org is on NA27 and is Enterprise Edition.

Comment: Agree, looks like a bug.  Linked issue occurred when 2+ leads shared an account id.  In your test code, if you change the lead creation to set `Company = 'Test' + 1', do you still see the same behavior?  Since you aren't setting an account, wonder if it's treating duplicate Company values in the same way.  Not an answer but maybe another data point.